# Set selected item after loading data from server

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

In AngularJS, what is considered best practice for loading initial data and setting selected options? For example, say I have two services as shown below

**A service to load initial configuration**

```
app.service('ConfigService', function($timeout){
  var self = this;
  self.config = {};

  // simulate loading configuration from server
  self.loadConfig = function(){
    $timeout(function(){
      self.config = {preferredId:2};
    }, 2000);
  };

  self.loadConfig();
});
```

**A service to load initial data**

```
app.service('DataService', function($timeout){
  var self = this;
  self.data = [];

  // simulate fetching data from server
  self.loadData = function(){
    $timeout(function(){
      self.data = [{id:1, name: 'apple'}, {id:2, name:'mango'}, {id:3, name:'papaya'}];
    }, 3000);
  };

  self.loadData();
});
```

In my controller, I want to display a list of choices using data from service 2 and also set the currently selected option using configuration from service 1. I currently use a $scope.$watch to set the selected option as shown below

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, DataService, ConfigService) {

  $scope.selectedItem = null;
  $scope.DataService = DataService;
  $scope.ConfigService = ConfigService;

  // set selected item
  $scope.setSelectedItem = function(){
    if(ConfigService.config && ConfigService.config.preferredId){
        $scope.selectedItem = _.find(DataService.data, function(item){
            return item.id == ConfigService.config.preferredId;
        });
    }
  }; 

  // use watchers to update the selected value if the service loads after the controller
  $scope.$watchCollection('DataService', function() {
       $scope.setSelectedItem();
   });
   $scope.$watchCollection('ConfigService', function() {
       $scope.setSelectedItem();
   });

});
```

Is using $scope.$watch for this purpose considered bad practice? I can alternatively modify my code to listen for events and do the same thing as shown below (service code omitted for brevity)

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, DataService, ConfigService, $rootScope) {

  $scope.selectedItem = null;
  $scope.DataService = DataService;
  $scope.ConfigService = ConfigService;

  // set selected item
  $scope.setSelectedItem = function(){
    if(ConfigService.config && ConfigService.config.preferredId){
        $scope.selectedItem = _.find(DataService.data, function(item){
            return item.id == ConfigService.config.preferredId;
        });
    }
  }; 

  $rootScope.$on('DataService:loaded',function(){
    $scope.setSelectedItem();
  });
  $rootScope.$on('ConfigService:loaded',function(){
    $scope.setSelectedItem();
  });

});
```

Is this considered the correct or preferred way to set my selected option or is there another better way that I have missed?

**Plunk using $scope.$watch**

http://plnkr.co/edit/9Lb6cmirR2J8AiuYiuwU?p=preview

**Plunk using $rootScope.$broadcast and $rootScope.$on**

http://plnkr.co/edit/ltRF2KSnz0zXtFxXU5hE?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hoping that this will be helpful because I've sort of changed your example a bit. :)

So, first off, your simulation with the server using `$timeout` isn't typically what you would see.  A `service` usually acts as a conduit to the data, but the state wouldn't necessarily stay around on `self` as you have done.  Doing this necessitates a `$watch` on the data in order to take action (like bind to the scope).

In [my fork of your plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/isoiFpayUokYTEvgkVrO?p=preview), instead of use only `$timeout`, I use `$q` as a way to set up a promise.  This is more typical of how the actual `$http` service works in Angular.  So, this is now the service code:

```
// service that controls user configuration
app.service('ConfigService', function($timeout, $q){
  var self = this;

  // simulate loading configuration from server
  self.loadConfig = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $timeout(function(){
      deferred.resolve({preferredId:2});
    }, 2000);

    return deferred.promise;
  };
});

// service that controls data
app.service('DataService', function($timeout, $q){
  var self = this;

  // simulate fetching data from server
  self.loadData = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $timeout(function(){
      deferred.resolve([{id:1, name: 'apple'}, {id:2, name:'mango'}, {id:3, name:'papaya'}]);
    }, 3000);

    return deferred.promise;
  };

});
```

The data remains unchanged.  However, we now have a promise to deal with directly in the controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, DataService, ConfigService) {

  $scope.selectedItem = null;
  $scope.selectedOption = {};

  ConfigService.loadConfig().then(function(data) {
    $scope.selectedOption = { id: data.preferredId };
  });

  DataService.loadData().then(function(options) {
     $scope.possibleOptions = options;
  });
});
```

Here, I handle the data coming back from the promise resolution and bind to the scope.  That is all.  You'll notice one other thing here. I'm wrapping the `preferredId` in and object with an `id` property:

```
$scope.selectedOption = { id: data.preferredId };
```

This allows me to use the `track by` syntax in the `ng-options` to automatically set the selected item ([documentation with select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)):

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="item.name for item in possibleOptions track by item.id"></select>
  </body>
```

This is the typical way you would handle this sort of thing, IMO.

If the data *changed* in some way *outside* of this controller, then I would then start to look at events as a way to keep the controller in sync.

Comment: Your code is pretty close to what I am looking for with the only difference being that my services are responsible for loading their own data and keeping it in sync with the server. If that is the case, would an event be preferred over a watch for performance reasons?

Comment: Certainly preferred over the deep watch for performance reasons.  An event also, seems a more natural fit, IMO. You only want to respond when the event occurs.